# Android account Google getauthtoken value null

Tags: android, accountmanager

My code:

```
Account[] accts = mgr.getAccountsByType("com.google");
Account acct = accts[0];
System.out.println("account:" + acct);

AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> acc=mgr.getAuthToken(acct, OAUTH2_SCOPE, null, null,
                    null, null);
Bundle authTokenBundle = acc.getResult();
String authToken = authTokenBundle.get(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN).toString();
System.out.println("authtoken:"+authToken);
```

The code works after every 1 day. The authentication token comes today but it wont come tomorrow and it works again the day after that. A very weird problem.

my `OAUTH2_SCOPE = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"`

the `getAuthToken()` function returns null value.

Answer (score 1):

Use the value for OAUTH@_SCOPE as "oauth2:https://mail.google.com/"

Answer (score 0):

It could be to do with making calls on the `Account` after `accountManager.setAuthToken()`.

See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19242193/2597978